# How to pass the Kitver to the job using Jenkins build promotion?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I need to promote a deploy job, but have only the Kitver which is a parameter passed from the last downstream job. 
So let us say the following jobs
A builds and compile and creates a zip with version and pushes to a ftp server. I don't store artifacts on job workspace.

B does the deployment by taking the Kitver passed on to it from A.

C does the testing

All the above is a build pipeline process so all of them happens sequentially.

D is a Prod deploy job, not in the pipeline but needs to be connected to A job using a promotion process. How to pass the Kitver to this job using promotion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the job A is the one that has the promotion process configured.

Perhaps you would store the Kitver into a file and archive it has a build artifact.

When the promotion process runs, it has a parameter, PROMOTED_BUILD, which is the build which is being promoted. If you pass that number to job D as a parameter, D can get the file and read the Kitver.

Alternatively you can get the file in the promotion process, read the file and pass Kitver as a parameter to D. Please note that this has to be done carefully. The promotion process runs in the same workspace as build A. The promotion process may be running at the same time as the next build of A, so they must take care not to touch or delete each other's files.

It would be safer to simply pass PROMOTED_BUILD to D and let D do all the complicated things because D will have its own workspace.